# Basic CRUD operations with Codeigniter and Datamapper

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm totally new at Codeigniter and Datamapper and i have a very fundamental question that can't be answered by myself searching in the documentation.

I have a very simple database with 3 tables:

```
 student
 courses
 student_courses
```

Now, i understand how works the relationships, do CRUD operation with CI, etc.....but how can i stablish the relationship between students and courses using a form that have to be fill it by an user?

Imagine i have a form where an user have to fill the name of an student and select two or more courses...how the controller have to look like?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

First off, using Datamapper with CI, it will be easier if you named the 'student' table 'students'. Then the join table 'courses_students' (thanks Shauna).  Your models would then be 'student' and 'course'.

The controller for the form could be something like this (ideally, you'd put the form in the View):

```
function form() {
     echo "<form method='post' action='submitForm'>";
     echo "<input type='text' name='student_name'>";
     echo "<select name='courses[]' multiple='multiple'>";
     $c = new Course();
     $c->get();
     foreach($c as $course) {
         echo "<option value='{$course->id}'>{$course->name}</option>";
     }
     echo "</select>";
     echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>";
}
```

The controller to submit the form (without validation or XSS checks):

```
function submitForm() {
     $s = new Student();
     $s->name = $this->input->post('student_name');
     // an initial save to the Students table, might be omitted
     $s->save();
     $course_array = $this->input->post('courses');
     // loop through the Courses, get them from db, and save the relationship
     foreach($course_array as $k=>$v) {
          $c = new Course($v);
          $s->save($c);
     }
}
```

A couple of notes: this is a quick, dirty example. Doing those multiple saves could slow things down if there are many Courses select, and there's probably a way using Datamapper to save the array in one statement, but I'd need to research that.

Comment: CI Datamapper looks for Join tables by looking for names that are alphabetical, so you'll actually want `courses_students` for your Join table name.